# Handling data - Spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

As far as I know, spark structured streaming is fault Tolerance by using checkpoints.

I want to read from kafka.

So let's say that I use checkpoint, and then for some reason my code crashes / I stops it, then I expect that when I rerun the code it will recover the processed data.

My problem is that in the reading configuration, if I set the offset to earliest so after rerunning the code I will read the same data again, and if I put latest I won't read the data between the code crashes til I rerun the code.

Does there is a way to read only unread messages from kafka with spark 2.3 - structured streaming (pyspark), and to recover processed data from checkpoints?

Answer (score 0):

It depends where your code crashes. You don't need to set it earliest, you can set it to latest. You can always recover from checkpointing and reprocess the data, [Here is the semantics of checkpointing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#recovery-semantics-after-changes-in-a-streaming-query)

Comment: Let's say I set it to latest and my code runs for hours and it's working just fine. And then, suddenly, something went wrong, and it crashes, and it takes me 1 hour to rerun the code. So when I rerun the data that was being processed will be recovered by the checkpoints, but O won't get  the data that got into the kafka topic in the last hour, because I set it to latest, and it means I will get only new data. How can I get this last hour data too, without reading the data I have already read? @deo

Comment: I want that every time I run the code it will recover from checkpoint if something went wrong in the last run, and I want it to read only unread messages from kafka.